# Showing Website on WebView by using ImageButton in Android

Tags: android, android-webview, imagebutton

```
private ImageButton imagebutton;

 private void init(){

        imagebutton =(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);  
        final WebView WebView1 = new WebView(this);
        WebView1.addView(imagebutton);
        imagebutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override 

            public void onClick(View v) {

                 setContentView(WebView1);
                 WebView1.loadUrl("http://www.xxx.com/");

            }
        });


 }
```

```
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/WebView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/WebView1"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/WebView1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:src="@drawable/logo_xxx_xxx" 
    android:onClick="@+id/imagebutton"
    />
```

I want to make a small application that can open a website by webview in my apps.I have 1 "imagebutton" and "WebView" component.When I click on imagebutton that have a "logo" of my website, my apps should open my website on same screen.How can I do this?

Comment: Why dont you add imageview above webView rathar than adding in webView itself.

Comment: don't add the imagebutton into your webView

Comment: Why should I add imageview? I just want to show my website after I click on imagebutton...

Comment: my imagebutton will open website in same window.

Comment: so change the title, it describes a different problem from what you want.. now, my question is, what happens when you exit from the website? it should show the 'buttons' area or those button links are always visible, even when the webpage is open?

Comment: now I got an error called "Fatal Exception" also I cannot see my imagebutton with its logo.

Comment: you didn't answer my question.. why are you trying to add button to webview? are you trying to create "Back" and "Forward" buttons, like in Chrome or Internet Explorer?

Comment: I just want to open my website in the apps so I'm using imagebutton in order to open it.When user run my application she/he should see imagebutton with "logo" then click the logo and open my website in same screen not in other page.

Comment: http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-webview-example/ look at this tutorial

Comment: This is so simple example in order to open a new website by using any component to achieve it.

Comment: but imagebutton and button has different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not followed your layout because I think  your are a bit confussed with:

- fill_parent and alignements. Why are you using alignements respect to the webview when you are setting fill_parent on it? fill_parent tries to occupy all the parent view.
- onClick calls to a java function defined on the same activity you set the content view. Not what you put `@+id/imagebutton`. By the way you are setting an onclick listener to the imagebutton, so you can safelly remove the onClick on your layout.

I have used a layout where the image is going to be on the center on the screen and when you click is going to load a website on the webview, once loaded the icon will dissapear and the webview will be showed.

Simple RelativeLayout activity_webview.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webviewactivity_webview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:visibility="invisible" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/webviewactivity_imagebutton"
    android:layout_width="45dp"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:contentDescription="@null" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Code:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

public class WebViewActivity extends Activity {

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_webiview);
    final WebView wb = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webviewactivity_webview);
    wb.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    final ImageButton ib = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.webviewactivity_imagebutton);
    ib.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            wb.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");

        }

    });
    wb.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url){
            ib.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            wb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);             
        }
    });
}

}
```

As you see I used the default logo that comes when you create an Android project.
Adjust the attributes of the layout to what you really want.

I suggest you to start with simple activities to practice with layouts.

Comment: everything good but when I click imagebutton desired website couldnt open even google.com btw there is no problem in my internet connection.

Comment: Add (only the permission tag)`<manifest xlmns:android...><uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>...</manifest>` on the manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

this code is working for me

```
WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
```

put this code in your ImageView's onClick listener

Comment: It's a stupid question, but did you put internet permissions in the manifest? if yes, can you post your logcat?

Answer (score 0):

```
               final WebView wb = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webviewactivity_webview);
               wb.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
               wb.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
               WebSettings webSettings = wb.getSettings();
               webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
               webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
               wb.loadURL("http://www.google.co.in");
```